# What do these singular circumstances mean in Isaiah 13:12 concerning man?

Tags: isaiah

The context strongly suggests circumstances in the endtimes, especially the events highlighted in verse 10, being familiar language even in the gospels.

Isaiah 13:

> 10 For the stars of heaven and the constellations thereof shall not give their light: the sun shall be darkened in his going forth, and the moon shall not cause her light to shine.
>   11 And *I will punish the world for their evil*, and *the wicked for their iniquity*; and I will cause the arrogancy of the proud to cease, and will lay low the haughtiness of the terrible.
>   12 **I will make a man more precious than fine gold**; even a man than the golden wedge of Ophir.
>   13 *Therefore I will shake the heavens, and the earth* shall remove out of her place, in the wrath of the LORD of hosts, and *in the day of his fierce anger*.

What is the meaning of **I will make man more precious than fine gold**?

Comment: Isaiah 13 foretells the destruction of Babylon (13:19).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do the Biblical author's value more than fine gold?

**1 Peter 1:6-7** - In this you rejoice, though now for a little while, if necessary, you have been grieved by various trials, so that the tested genuineness of your faith — **more precious than gold that perishes** though it is tested by fire—may be found to result in praise and glory and honour at the revelation of Jesus Christ.

**Psalm 19:7-10** - The law of the Lord is perfect,
reviving the soul;
  the testimony of the Lord is sure,
making wise the simple;
  the precepts of the Lord are right,
rejoicing the heart;
  the commandment of the Lord is pure,
enlightening the eyes;
  the fear of the Lord is clean,
enduring forever;
  the rules of the Lord are true,
and righteous altogether.
  **More to be desired are they than gold,

even much fine gold;**
  sweeter also than honey
and drippings of the honeycomb.

**Psalm 119:127** - **My fruit is better than gold**, even fine gold, and my yield than choice silver.

The new Covenant promise was to give believers a new heart, and a new spirit within, and the promise to remove their heart of stone and instead give a heart of flesh (**Ezekiel 36:26**) BUT ALSO to put YHWH's law within them written on these new hearts (**Jer 31:33**).

> Therefore it stands to reason that if YHWH's law and precepts are **more valuable than fine gold** than those who have it on their hearts are more precious than fine gold too.  **Lam 4:2** calls these people '***the precious sons of Zion***'.  Though they are worth their weight in gold are regarded {by the world} as earthen pots, mere work of a potter's hands.

I would caution that it's an error to suggest this is only circumstances of the end-times, since if this all happened with the New Covenant and the New Covenant was the shedding of Yehshua's blood it's a denial that the New Covenant has happened; unless you count the 'endtimes' as starting with the Messiah.

> These are circumstances of the Messianic age.  **Christ-likeness is that which is more valuable than fine gold**.

Comment: So it's this category that the Most High considers ''man.'' 
What is the label for the rest of the people outside of this bracket of 'precious ones more than the gold of ophir'? Yes, the end of days started with Him, John 5:25, etc

Comment: The verse cited above is talking about a specific people (a man), not all people (all men), since not all people are like Christ or have this quality of possessing a new heart.